# Rolling a fair die and removing 1 dollar from the table each time

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are four dollar bills on the table. Your roll a fair die repeatedly. Every time you fail to get a six, one dollar bill is removed. When you get your first six, you get to take the money that remains on the table. If the money runs out before you get a six, you’ve lost and the game is over. Let $X$ be the amount of your award. Find the range and the probability mass function of $X$.

So I know the range to be some set, $S=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, where you can win nothing or four dollars.

However I am struggling to find the PMF. So far I know for... $$P(X=4)=1/6$$
Then I try to continue with the complement rule to figure out the probability of rolling a six on the 2nd roll with $$P(X=1-(5/6)^n)$$ When I get to the fifth roll (winning no money), and add up all the probabilities, they are much greater than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of getting a six the first time, is, as you observed, $1/6$.
The probability of getting the **first** six

-- on the first roll, is ${1\over 6}$ -- you win $4$ dollars.

-- on the second roll, is ${5\over 6}{1\over 6}$ -- you win $3$ dollars.

-- on the third roll is ${5\over 6}{5\over 6}{1\over 6}$ -- you win $2$ dollars.

-- on the fourth roll is ${5\over 6}{5\over 6}{5\over 6}{1\over 6}$ -- you win 1 dollar.

If you haven't got your first six in any of the first four rolls, you are out. There is no fifth roll.

So your probability to win at least one dollar, is:

$${1\over 6}+{5\over 36}+{25\over 216}+{125\over 1296}\approx 0.51$$

So interestingly, you are more likely to win something than not to win at all. The expected winning is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^3\left({5\over 6}\right)^k{1\over 6}(4-k)\approx 1.41$$

So if you play this game a lot of times, then on the average you'll make about one dollar and forty cents.